# Why is my header comprised inside another div? (2 sections not stacking)

Tags: html, css

Here is a basic question. I'd like to understand why the HTML element in my basic page are behaving the way they are, if someone could help me out.

Here's my code

```
<body>

<div id="wrapper">

    <header>

        <a id="logo" href="#">Evolvefitnesscoaching</a>

         <nav>

        <ul class="nav">
        <li><a href="#">Blogue</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Une Question?</a></li>
        </ul>

         </nav>

    </header>


    <section id="slider">
        <div id="cta">
        <h2>Perdre du poids, une habitude à la fois!</h2>
        <h3>Changez votre corps et votre vie, avec un coaching personnalisé par des   
            professionnels de la perte de poids et de l’activité physique.</h3>
        </div>
    </section>


    <section id="apropos">
    <h1>Avec evolvefitness, blah blah blah</h1>
    </section>


</div>
```

Here's my css

```
body {

            margin: 0px;

        }

        header {


            width: 100%;
            height: 80px;
            position:absolute;
            background-color: darkgrey;

        }

        nav {
            width: 250px;
            height: 100%;
            position: relative;
            background-color: cyan;
            float: right;

        }

        .nav {
            list-style: none;

        }

        .nav li {
            display: inline;
            margin-right: 10px;

        }

        .nav li a {

            text-decoration: none;
            color: white;
            font-size:1.1em;

        }

        .nav li a:hover {

            color:black;
        }

        #logo {


        }

        #slider {
            display: block;
            background-color: yellow;
            width:100%;
            height:700px;
        }

        #cta {

            margin-top:px;
            width: 500px;
            height: 300px;
            background-color: aquamarine;

        }

        #apropos {
            width:100%;
            height:300px;
            text-align:center;
        }
```

Now, what I don't understand is that the section #slider is not under, as per block, the header section but actually underneath (what I mean is that the header is comprised inside the section #slider), when, as far as I know, it should be over it, as if 2 blocks are stacking one over the other.

How is that so? The one called apropos is behaving as i'm expecting it to behave, ie, it's under the #slider section (blocks stacking). But the #slider section is not behaving like what i'm expecting, either because I don't understand well or something is off. Because of that, when I add another div inside of the slider section (#cta), it adds a margin between the body and the top part of my document.

Very basic question but i'm just starting out, if someone could help me :\

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry i've edited the css in now!

Comment: you also have your wrapper in the wrong place you should put it around your sections

Comment: http://liveweave.com/ylUDoG

Comment: Hi Rachel. Could you please explain why or point to me a ressource to better understand this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your header is absolutely positioned and thus removes itself from the rest of the rendered layers.

Change its position into 'relative' (position: relative) and everything will work as expected.

Comment: Thanks you sir that did it! Looks like I need a better understanding of positioning.

Comment: Sure thing - here's a great article about it:
https://css-tricks.com/absolute-relative-fixed-positioining-how-do-they-differ/
Also, please select it as the answer if it helped

Answer (score 0):

The end tag of `#wrapper` should be placed above the closing `body` tag. Hmm it was just there, you changed something?

Comment: I think I just forgot to copy the </body> in! Seems like my problem was position:relative on my header!